# Using clear vs resetting the object with a ConcurrentDictionary in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class like this.

```
public class LocalizationHandler
{
    private ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> _localeKeyValue;

    public LocalizationHandler(DatabaseConnection dbConnection)
    {
        Load(dbConnection);
    }

    public void Load(DatabaseConnection dbConnection)
    {
        _localeKeyValue = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();
        _localeKeyValue = FetchLocale(dbConnection);
    }

    private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> FetchLocale(DatabaseConnection dbConnection)
    {
        // This will actually do something soon.
        return new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();
    }
}
```

Now, the method `Load` can be called when it first needs to initialize and fetch the locale from the database, but it can also be called if you need to refresh it from the database.

My question is, instead of just assigning `_localeKeyValue` in the constructor and clearing it from `Load` method, am I better to just assign it on every call to `Load` or is there a large performance hit?

Is it worth assigning it in the constructor and only clearing it inside `Load` ?

If I didn't make it clear to why the dictionary needs to be cleared, is because `Load` could be being called to just refresh it, and we want it to act as a new clean dictionary, and to forget the old values.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `Load` function reads the data from some external source (e.g., a file or a database), creating a new `ConcurrentDictionary` would be completely negligible, so that really shouldn't be a concern.

Creating a new `ConcurrentDictionary` each time you load is probably the safer approach. In case some other caller holds a reference to the old dictionary, clearing it mid-program may have unexpected side effects.